# Facebook Fan Page Id in associated Facebook App

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I am developing a facebook application which required to get below information while load.

- Facebook Fan Page URL / Id on which the application has been added.
- If the user who is accessing this application from specific page is admin of that page or not.

I am developing this application in ASP.Net and I am using Facebook Graph API.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me share some insights

Firstly, I would strongly suggest that you use Microsoft's [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) instead of using plain calls in your .NET project.

---

## Steps

With the current API, you can do this in your ADMIN Page

- Ask the user to connect and ask for manage pages permission (`manage_page`)
- with the permisions to manage the pages, you can easily fill up a dropdown with all pages that the user have
- Ask the user to add your app to it's own page as a tab using `http://facebook.com/add.php?api_key=[API_KEY]&pages=1&page=[PAGE_ID]`

Now that you have your app running on the user page, you need a way to check if that page is running inside Facebook as a Tab or not, and what's the Page Id that is running from.

- In your App Tab Url page that you specified, ask for the [`signed_request`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) and verify the `Data` as it has the `["page"]["id"]` that you need so you can check against the saves Page_Id that you should have saved on the ADMIN area when your user adds your app to it's facebook page.

I hope this helps.

## Code

To login and **request all user pages**:

```
<select class="facebook-page-list" disabled="disabled">
    <option>Facebook pages</option></select>

<script>
<!--
  FB.init({
     appId: 'API_KEY',
     cookie: true,
     status: true,
     xfbml: true
  });

  FB.api('/me', function (user) {
     if (user != null) {
        if (user.error) {
           $(".fb-login").show();
        } else {
           // example from Facebook
           var image = document.getElementById('image');
           image.src = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + user.id + '/picture';
           var name = document.getElementById('name');
           name.innerHTML = user.name

           // get all user Pages
           facebookGetPages();
        }
     }
  });

  function facebookGetPages() {
     FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.session) {
           access_token = response.session.access_token;
           FB.api(
           {
              method: 'fql.multiquery',
              access_token: access_token,
              queries: {
                 query1: 'select page_id from page_admin where type <> "APPLICATION" and uid = ' + response.session.uid,
                 query2: 'select page_id, name, page_url from page where page_id in (select page_id from #query1)'
              }
           }, function (queries) {
              if (queries.error_msg)
                 alert(queries.error_msg);
              else {
                 pages = queries[1].fql_result_set;

                 $(".facebook-page-list").empty();
                 for (i = 0; i < pages.length; i++)
                    $(".facebook-page-list").append("<option value='" + pages[i].page_id + "'>" + pages[i].name + "</option>");
                 $(".facebook-page-list").attr("disabled", false);
              }
           });
        } else {
           // no user session available, someone you dont know
        }
     });
  }
//--> 
</script>
```

To **get the Page ID** from your app:

```
ViewBag.signed_request = "can't get id";
dynamic signed_request = FacebookWebContext.Current.SignedRequest;
if(signed_request != null)
{
   ViewBag.signed_request = signed_request.Data.page.id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is really a great insight and knowledge. But I really can't make separate copies of application all the time. What I am trying to do is like explain in this YouTube video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oORqblE28HI). I just want to replicate something like that.

Comment: added the javascript code and the C# code for how you can request all pages, add your app as a tab to the user page and then know how you can see witch page is requesting your app.